# TortoiseGit problems "Is Files"

Tags: tortoisegit

I will be happy for any suggestion, not only answers.

My TortoiseGit is malfunctioning on my Win7 64bit machine.

Notice I can still work correctly from the command line with my github repositories.

#### The problems

- right-click rep\commit gives the followin:

  - Single **Modified File** named: `Is-files` with no extension and with status `conflict` (I don't have such a file)
  - Single **Not Versioned** file named: `git: 'File' is not a git command. See 'git --help'. Did you mean this?Is-files` with extension `.Did you mean this?Is-files` and with status `Unknown` (of course I don't have such a file)
- Trying to right-click a rep\settings\remotes I get a pop-up saying: `git: 'Files' is not a git command. See 'git --help'. Did you mean this? Is-files` with a single ok button. then clicking ok shows an empty remote list. notice that when I type `git remote` in the command line I do get the list of remotes.

problems are for all my repositories

#### Things I tried

- uninstall\reinstall both TortoiseGit and msysgit
- various TortoiseGit versions: 1.6.3.0 and 1.6.2.0
- git gc
- git fsck
- git prune

I'm using msysgit 1.7.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by the following procedure:

- Uninstall TortoiseGit - then restart
- Uninstall TortoiseSVN - then restart
- Find registry folders with the words "TortoiseSVN" or "TortoiseGit" and erase them
- Install TortoiseGit - then restart

Surprisingly *that* worked.